# Vue3 Custom Component v-model doesn't work inside a div

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component

I have written a custom Vue3 component for form input, and parent components should be able to use v-model to bind the value of the input field. I have done this successfully in basic form (which is shown in my first snippet below). However, it only seems to work when the input element is the parent element in the component template. If I surround the input element in a div (within the custom component), it stops working.

This is the working component in its basic form.

```
<template>
    <input v-model="value" class="form-control form-in" type="text" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder" @input="updateValue()"/>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'FormInput',
        props: {
            name: String,
            placeholder: String,
        },
        data () {
            return {
                value: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateValue() {
                this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.value)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

This is utilised in a parent Vue file.

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="ml-2">Name</label>
            <FormInput
                name="name"
                v-model="form.name"
                ref="name"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is all working as expected. When I type in this input, the value of 'form.name' is being updated correctly. However, I wanted to add some more features to my input component, e.g. a label afterwards that could be used for a validation message. As a Vue component requires a single parent component, I surround both the input and label elements in a div.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="value" :class="{ 'validation-failed' : validation_failed == true}" class="form-control form-in" type="text" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder" @input="updateValue()"/>
        <label class="font-weight-bold ml-2 mt-1 text-danger" v-if="validation_failed">{{ validation_msg }}</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

I notice now that the v-model binding on the parent component is no longer working. To troubleshoot I rolled this all back, and started by just adding the div tag:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="value" class="form-control form-in" type="text" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder" @input="updateValue()"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

This also isn't working, so it's to do with the input being inside a div.

When I debug the 'FormInput' component, I can see its 'value' is being updated with the text input.

I'm assuming I'm missing some fundamental rule of Vue as to why this is not working, but I haven't been able to figure this out from Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You could make some tweaks here:

- Vue 3 supports multiple root elements in component templates
- Since you use `v-model` on `<input>` there's no need to use its `@input` otherwise do just 1-way binding without `v-model`
- But better use a standard `v-model` implementation with `computed`
- You don't need an extra `validation_failed` since the presence of `validation_msg` is enough
- You could consider Composition API with `<script setup>` as the latest recommend way to make components in Vue 3.
- You could consider move `<script>` as the first section, again the latest recommended way

```
<template>
        <input v-model="value" :class="{ 'validation-failed' : validationMsg}" class="form-control form-in" type="text" :name="name" :placeholder="placeholder"/>
        <label class="font-weight-bold ml-2 mt-1 text-danger" v-if="validationMsg">{{ validationMsg }}</label>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'FormInput',
        props: {
            name: String,
            placeholder: String,
            modelValue: String
        },
        computed: {
            validationMsg(){
                return this.value.match(/^\d*$/) ? '' : 'Not a number!!!'
            },
            value: {
                get(){
                    return this.modelValue;
                },
                set(value){
                    this.$emit('update:modelValue', value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is all very useful. Regarding the multiple root elements, it seems that VSCode must be interpreting my file as Vue 2 as it's showing the syntax error, but I don't actually seem to have an issue when serving the file on my dev server. The validation message is actually being returned from an API call, which is why I'm not using computed for this.